# Node.js `require` into an array instead of a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

It is possible to `var x = require('x.js')` and use `x` later on to access all the nice stuff. What is the closest way to build an array of required things, like:

```
var xs = [require('a.js'), require('b.js')]
```

and then access the exported features as `xs[0].feature` and `xs[1].feature`?

Comment: @JordanHendrix yes, it does not work. So, I am asking for the closest similar way to do it.

Comment: @JordanHendrix alright, half an hour later I see that I must have made a mistake and it is indeed possible to `require` an array of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have very good reason to do this, it should probably be avoided. But it can be done quite simply using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var xs = ['foo.js', 'bar.js', 'baz.js'].map(require);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
var x = [];
var requiredLibraries = ['a.js', 'b.js', 'c.js'];

requiredLibraries.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    x.push(require(element));
});
```

**EDIT** Please note that I don't think this is a good idea, because of confusion it might bring and lower the readability of your code, if nothing else.

Comment: Suppose you have several files that each provide one function. And you have a setting that chooses one of those functions. In my opinion, it makes sense to build an array (or a Map) of functions and index it with the given option. So, I do not think it harms readability.

Comment: Well, in that case I guess it could make sense, but hopefully you will remember what you did there in six months when you come back to work on it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Both getRoutes and postRoutes are files .js (getRoutes.js and postRoutes.js)

I used this approach to create an index.js with all my routes.

index.js

```
const routes = [require("./getRoutes"), require("./postRoutes")];

module.exports = { routes };

// OR

const routes = ["./getRoutes", "./postRoutes"].map(require);

module.exports = { routes };
```

getRoutes.js and postRoutes.js they would look something like that

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { users } = require("../controllers");

router.post("/user", users);

module.exports = router;
```